# pyinstaller and loading pickle file

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, pyinstaller

Has anyone worked with `pyinstaller` to create windows executables from python scripts? I'm trying to create an executable that loads a pickle file but not successful.

```
import pickle
filename='test.sav'
try:
    model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
    print('model loaded')
except:
    print('An error occurred.')
```

When run with python 3, it works and loads the `model` correctly but when run with the executable created by `pyinstaller`, it will through an exception. Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: I'm also running into the same problem... if any of you guys solve this, it would be nice to know

Answer (score 1):

Im using kivy with pickle and it works correctly.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.config import Config
import pickle
FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60.0
Config.set('graphics','multisamples',2)

a = []
class Display(BoxLayout):

   def save(self,text):
       with open('db.prz','wb') as file:
           pickle.dump(text,file)
   def loads(self):
       with open('db.prz','rb') as file:
           a = pickle.load(file)
       print(a)

class TestApp(App):
     def build(self):
        a = Display()
        return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
<Display>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: kvtext
        size_hint_y : 0.2
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: 'Save'
            on_press: root.save(kvtext.text)
        Button:
            text: 'Load'
            on_press: root.loads()
```

Spec File Changes:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

a = Analysis(
         datas=[('C:\\Users\\mnt\\Documents\\build_test\\test.kv','.')],
coll = COLLECT(
        *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
```

Note that im not adding my file 'db.prze' to data in `Analysis()`

I also installed pyi from github not from pip.

If you are loading class object, import its class from file.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is does kivy produce an executable file from the python code?